# EF Merge data from multiple entities into single entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have five cascaded tables, called activity tables with following format :

[image: Table Schema]

I would like to merge the data into single entity where each record would be unique by PeriodID, Activity and Site. Hence, would like to read them into following view model :

```
public class PivotViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Period ID")]
    public Int32 PeriodID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Site")]
    public string SiteID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    public string Product { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Activity")]
    public string Activity { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    public double? Value { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value1")]
    public double? Value1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value2")]
    public double? Value2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value3")]
    public double? Value3 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value4")]
    public double? Value4 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value5")]
    public double? Value5 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure how should I write my Linq query so I can merge all 5 tables into same row by Period ID. I would prefer to do this my individual query rather than using union query.

When I do following, it will overwrite the last results.

```
var activityResult = db.OMS_Planned_Receipts.Where(p => p.Product == product)
  .Select(b => new PivotViewModel
  {
      Product = b.Product,
      PeriodID = b.PeriodID,
      SiteID = b.SiteID,
      Value = b.Value,
      Activity = "Planned"
  });

activityResult = db.OMS_System_Forecast.Where(p => p.Product == product)
  .Select(b => new PivotViewModel
  {
      Product = b.Product,
      PeriodID = b.PeriodID,
      SiteID = b.SiteID,
      Value = b.Value,
      Activity = "Forecast"
  });
```